# Facebook sharing in a J2ME application? Is there any facebook API for J2ME?

Tags: facebook, java-me

I need to share a text in Facebook from my J2ME app. Is there any Facebook API available for J2ME?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi there are some approaches in below link 
http://j2megroup.blogspot.com/2011/06/facebook-api-me-10-tutorial.html

But we preferred to do it another way. We have written some services(helpers) which connects to Facebook over php sdk. And we have used our simplified services. But this might require to have an application in Facebook side.

Comment: But, facebook didn't give API for j2me

Comment: Yes you are right there is no official J2Me apis from facebook. But that does not mean you can not fix your issue. If Facebook does not give you the answer you may use third parties as I have mentioned, or your own solution.

Comment: Is there any sample program to share in J2ME using third party API?

Answer (score 0):

There are no free libraries to do this. You can use Facebook APIs to do this.

Comment: There is no specific facebook API for J2ME. How to share without facebook API?

Comment: APIs are Facebook web API  which can be accessed from any device. So this is possible